# linux command for adding information

Tags: linux, command

Is there any way to find all .java files in a drive and add the text "author name :man"...with the linux command

Answer (score 2):

The simplest is ..

```
find ./ -name '*.java' -exec echo "author name :man" >> {} \;
```

DC

To explain what the above does

first `find` is the command. Its task is to find files that match certain criteria and optionally do things, it is a very powerful tool.

`./` is the directory to search in, in this case ./ means the current directory. If you want it to search the entire computer use `/` if you want it to search only a specific folder or sub folder use `/folder/subfolder` OR `cd` to that directory and use `./` as in the sample command above

`-name` tells find you are looking for a file with the name that follows it, in the example we are telling it to search for any file ending in `.java` thats why the wildcard `*` we put single quotes around the name as in `'*.java'` to prevent 'Shell expansion' google that for more information.

`-exec` tells find that for every file execute the command following it, in this case the command is `echo "author name :man" >> {}` which means echo(write) the string "author name :man" and append `>>` it to the found file. find replaces the token `{}` with the filename of the file, it is relative to the current folder e.g. the one you are in when you run the command. `\;` tells find this is the end of the command. further commands can follow it if you want (you must use a logical operation like `-and`).

so for a test run ssh into your server and run this

```
 find / -name '*.java'
```

This will find all files on your server with the .java extension. it could be a lot and might take a long time.

when that is done lets try to `-exec` something preferably something that wont cause any damage, so try this command

```
find / -name '*.java' -exec ls -alh {} \;
```

This tells find to run the ls command for each and every file ending in .java that it finds.

You should now be able to use find to do what you require

cd to the root of the folder that contains the java files you wish to modify and run the command
of course don't forget that appending plain text to a java file will break it. make sure the text is in the form of a comment.

perhaps a better command is

```
find ./ -name '*.java' -exec cat authors.txt >> {} \;
```

Where authors.txt contains the data you wish to add. the command above will append the entire content of authors.text to each and every .java file it finds.

Be careful this command is very powerful, and "with great power comes" ... something or other

In other words make sure you back everything up first BEFORE running a command that makes wholesale changes. you may regret it other wise

DC

Lastly to PREPEND the details to the files is a little more complicated as hhafez has stated you can use another script that does it for you.

create the script addauthor.sh ...

```
 #!/bin/bash
cat authors.txt > /tmp/tempfile
cat $1 >> /tmp/tempfile
cp --reply=yes /tmp/tempfile $1
```

and modify the find command to

```
find ./ -name '*.java' -exec sh addauthor.sh {} \;
```

Test it first

DC

Comment: chris' solution should work as is, just type at the command line and press enter and it should work.

Comment: with chris command a file {} is getting created.... but my question was to add my comments like /*man*/ on header of all .java files in a drive

Comment: not if you typed it correctly find replaces {} with the name of the file

Comment: hi... chris....can u please give me the step by step solution for executing the cmnd?

Comment: hafeez i tried u rsolution.... but it is not working... or plz tell me the to work it out

Comment: see above alteration to the answer

Answer (score 1):

do you want to do it in a destructive way or make a copy, assuming you don't mind doing it inline

`find . -name *.java -exec add_text.sh {}\;`

where `add_text.sh` looks something like this

```
#!/bin/sh
$input_file = $1
$header_file = /path/to/the/header/file/you/want/to/insert/
mv ${input_file} ${input_file}_tmp
cat $header_file ${input_file}_tmp > ${input_file}
```

Warning this is untested `:)`

Comment: This will, of course, append the file.  So it's a footer, not a header.

Comment: so I've changed my answer to add it to the header, so my solution should work as you expect. Might not work with names with space in the path

Comment: hi... what ever chris has given the solution... it is creating {} file adding the info....but i want the information to be added to all .java files...

Comment: plz help me out...i am in deep trouble

Comment: hafeez i am new to linux... can u actually ellaborate in steps?